# Chain rule related to relativistic momentum

Tags: special-relativity, momentum, differentiation

I am having trouble deriving the chain rule in the following:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial p^i}=\frac{\partial p_0}{\partial \vec{p}}\frac{\partial}{\partial p_0}+\frac{\partial}{\partial \vec{p}}.$$

The LHS is like a sum while the RHS is a vector. Also, I don't get why there is the first term in RHS. It would be of lot help if you could provide a detailed proof.

Given is that $i$ runs from 1 to 3 and $p_0^2-\vec{p}^2=0$.

Comment: The left hand side is not a sum until it is contracted with a similarly indexed term. Usually to prove a derivative/operator identity you should use it on an arbitrary test function

Comment: @Triatticus, can you show me or at least sketch out the proof of the expression.